# Importing from the contrib library fails

Tags: idris, idris2

I'm following the TDD book in Idris 2, and the [online documentation](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/typedd/typedd.html#chapter-10) gives the following advice:

> For the `VList` view in the exercise 4 after Chapter 10-2 import `Data.List.Views.Extra` from `contrib` library.

So I put this import in a source file (`example.idr`)

```
import Data.List.Views.Extra
```

But running `idris2 example.idr` fails with

```
Error: Module Data.List.Views.Extra not found
```

I believe the contrib library is correctly installed, because `contrib (0.5.1)` appears in the list printed by `idris2 --list-packages`.

How can Idris 2 be made to accept imports from the contrib library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to explicitly providing `-p` on the command line (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72042621/2954547)), you can also [define a package](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/packages.html#packages) for your project, using an IPKG file, wherein you can specify your dependencies.

Minimal example, to be placed in the top-level directory of your project:

```
package type-driven-development
depends = contrib
```

Then you can invoke Idris 2 with `idris2 --find-ipkg Example.idr`, and all of the `depends` will be included as if you had specified `-p` for each one.

The Idris 2 CLI also can generate a template IPKG file for you. The `idris2 --init` command will provide you with interactive prompts in order to fill in some basic values.

Comment: This seems better than having to remember all the dependencies :)

Answer (score 2):

The idris2 binary accepts a `--package` or `-p` argument to *add a package as a dependency*.

Invoking the interpreter with `idris2 -p contrib example.idr` allows the import to be resolved correctly.